# Laravel - Generate CSS from database

Tags: php, mysql, css, laravel-4

is it possible with Laravel (latest) to generate an css file "on the fly" from custom css code from the database?
I've stored the custom css code in "custom_css" (longtext) in my mysql db.

I just thought that I could output it via blade:

```
<style type="text/css">{{$custom_css}}</style>
```

But isn't there a possibility to generate a css "on the fly" and add it via link-tag?
Adding it via blade could extend my html code, I don't want that. I want a clean "html" (as much as possible).
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given your comments:

```
Route::get('/path/to/css', function() {
    // fetch your CSS and assign to $contents
    $response = Response::make($contents);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/css');
    return $response;
});
```

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. I know that, it was just an example code. Can I also do it in my route, without a controller ? Do I have to output a special header for that "file" ?

Comment: Are you preferring to have it return a file representing the css, or to simply echo the CSS in a <style> tag like you have above?

Comment: I rather prefer to output it to the link tag / file.

Comment: You will either need a controller or a Route that simply fetches the corresponding row/column from your database, and then returns the Content-Type of text/css.  I am amending my answer now.

Comment: In case anyone else wondered, the Response class used here corresponds to Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response.

Answer (score 0):

Generating CSS from database works the same way as reading database value using Laravel.
This is straightforward.

Example below retrieves css background value from settings table and displays it:

```
table: settings
---------------------------------------------
| ID | border_color | font_color | bg_color |
---------------------------------------------
| 1  | #EF0404      | #48B014    | #121BCC  |

Model: Setting
--------------
protected $fillable = [
  'border_color', 'font_color', 'bg_color'  
];

Controller: HomeController
--------------------------
use App\Setting;

public function index(){
  $colors = Setting::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit('1')->get();
  return view('home', [
    'colors' => $colors
  ]);
}

Route: home routing
-------------------
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

View: home.blade.php
--------------------
<html>
   <head>
      //iterating throuhg your color schemes styling
      @if(!empty($colors))
         @foreach($colors as $color)
           <style type="text/css">
             .bg_color{
                background: {{ $color->bg_color }} !important;
             }
           </style>
         @endforeach()
      @endif
   </head>
   <body>
      <p class="bg_color">
         Generating CSS from database using Laravel. <br />
         This must work.
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

I hope that this will help you.